# Websql Does not create tables

Tags: sqlite, web-sql

```
 db = window.openDatabase("javascript.db", "1.0", "My app", 2 * 1024 * 1024);
  db.transaction(function(tx){
      tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE topic (topic_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, topic_name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, 'topic description' TEXT)");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'topic' VALUES('IV','Interview','This quiz contains questions asked during most interviews.')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'topic' VALUES('AN','Angularjs','Questions relating to Angularjs')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'topic' VALUES('JQ','Jquery','Questions relating to Jquery')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'topic' VALUES('XT','Extra','Extra questions.')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'topic' VALUES('XP','Expert','This is the fourth stage.')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'topic' VALUES('AD','Advance','This is the third stage.')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'topic' VALUES('IM','Intermediate','This is the second stage.')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'topic' VALUES('BG','Beginner','You should start here.')");
      tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE question (question_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, question_code TEXT UNIQUE, question TEXT NOT NULL, option1 TEXT NOT NULL, option2 TEXT NOT NULL, option3 TEXT, option4 TEXT, hint TEXT)");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'question' VALUES(1,'BG0101','quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion1','option1','option2','option3','1000','hint1')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'question' VALUES(2,'BG0102','quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion2','option1','option2','option3','0100','hint2')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'question' VALUES(3,'BG0103','quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion3','option1','option2','option3','0010','hint3')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'question' VALUES(4,'BG0104','quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion4','option1','option2','option3','0001','hint4')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'question' VALUES(5,'BG0105','quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion5','option1','option2','option3','1100','hint5')"); 
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'question' VALUES(6,'BG0106','quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion6','option1','option2','option3','0110','hint6')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'question' VALUES(7,'BG0107','quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion7','option1','option2','option3','0011','hint7')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'question' VALUES(8,'BG0108','quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion8','option1','option2','option3','1001','hint8')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'question' VALUES(9,'BG0109','quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion9','option1','option2','option3','1010','hint9')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'question' VALUES(10,'BG0110','quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion10','option1','option2','option3','0101','hint10')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'question' VALUES(11,'BG0111','quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion11','option1','option2','option3','1110','hint11')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'question' VALUES(12,'BG0112','quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion12','option1','option2','option3','0111','hint12')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'question' VALUES(13,'BG0113','quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion13','option1','option2','option3','1011','hint13')"); 
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'question' VALUES(14,'BG0114','quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion14','option1','option2','option3','1101','hint14')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'question' VALUES(15,'BG0115','quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion15','option1','option2','option3','1111','hint15')"); 
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'question' VALUES(16,'BG0116','quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion16','option1','option2','option3','0011','hint16')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'question' VALUES(17,'BG0117','quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion17','option1','option2','option3','1001','hint17')"); 
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'question' VALUES(18,'BG0118','quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion18','option1','option2','option3','1010','hint18')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'question' VALUES(19,'BG0119','quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion19','option1','option2','option3','0101','hint19')"); 
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'question' VALUES(20,'BG0120','quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion quetion20','option1','option2','option3','1000','hint20')");
      tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE answer (question_id INTEGER REFERENCES question (question_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,question_code TEXT REFERENCES question (question_code) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, answer TEXT, answer_code INTEGER)"); 
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'answer' VALUES(1,'BG0101','remove if not needed',1000,'explian1')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'answer' VALUES(2,'BG0102','remove if not needed',100,'explian2')"); 
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'answer' VALUES(3,'BG0103','remove if not needed',10,'explian3')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'answer' VALUES(4,'BG0104','remove if not needed',1,'explian4')"); 
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'answer' VALUES(5,'BG0105','remove if not needed',1100,'explian5')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'answer' VALUES(6,'BG0106','remove if not needed',110,'explian6')"); 
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'answer' VALUES(7,'BG0107','remove if not needed',11,'explian7')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'answer' VALUES(8,'BG0108','remove if not needed',1001,'explian8')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'answer' VALUES(9,'BG0109','remove if not needed',1010,'explian9')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'answer' VALUES(10,'BG0110','remove if not needed',101,'explian10')"); 
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'answer' VALUES(11,'BG0111','remove if not needed',1110,'explian11')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'answer' VALUES(12,'BG0112','remove if not needed',111,'explian12')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'answer' VALUES(13,'BG0113','remove if not needed',1011,'explian13')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'answer' VALUES(14,'BG0114','remove if not needed',1101,'explian14')"); 
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'answer' VALUES(15,'BG0115','remove if not needed',1111,'explian15')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'answer' VALUES(16,'BG0116','remove if not needed',11,'explian16')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'answer' VALUES(17,'BG0117','remove if not needed',1001,'explian17')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'answer' VALUES(18,'BG0118','remove if not needed',1010,'explian18')"); 
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'answer' VALUES(19,'BG0119','remove if not needed',101,'explian19')");
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'answer' VALUES(20,'BG0120','remove if not needed',1000,'explian20')");
      tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE image (question_id INTEGER REFERENCES question (question_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, img_src TEXT)");
      tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE user (topic_id TEXT REFERENCES topic (topic_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, attempt INTEGER, score INTEGER)"); 
      tx.executeSql("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX question_code ON question (question_code)"); 



  });
```

The above code create a Database called javascriot.db but it does not create tables and rows what could be the problem? 
I am new to websql and do not know how to debug? Can someone correct my code and tell me how to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSQL calls are asynchronous, so assuming your SQL syntax is correct the problem is that you try to insert data before tables are created. What you need to do is create table(s) in first call, and insert data through success callback. Error callback will give you information if something goes wrong.

General syntax (described in in [WebSQL spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#asynchronous-database-api)):

```
executeSql(sqlStatement, optional arguments, optional callback, optional errorCallback);
```

In your case:

```
tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE topic (topic_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, topic_name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, 'topic description' TEXT)", null, 
    function (transaction, sqlResultSet) {     
        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'topic' VALUES('IV','Interview','This quiz contains questions asked during most interviews.')", null, null, 
            function(transaction, error) {
                console.log('error on insert: ' + error.message);
            });
       // more inserts into 'topic' table ...
    }, function (transaction, error) {
        console.log('error on table create: ' + error.message);
    });

// more create table/insert
```